# Conversion form array to json for tree format. (php)

Tags: php, json

I've problem to make array dir (folder and files) to json conversion according to the following structure:

[here](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1093130#graph.json)

I try and try and search in web but nothing work.
Last code I write for this task this:

```
<?php
$path = 'data';
function get_Dir($path){
$dir = scandir($path);
$filesss = array();

$a = 0;
foreach($dir as $v){
    if($v == '.' || $v == '..') continue;

    if(!is_dir($path.'/'.$v)){
        $files[] = 'name:'.basename($v).','.'size:3938';
    }else{
        $files['name'] = basename($path.'/'.$v);
        //$change = basename($path.'/'.$v);
        $files['children'.$a] = get_dir($path.'/'.$v);

    }
    $a++;
}

return $files;
}
?>
```

Please help.
Thank you.

Comment: What does that have to do with JSON? You're just building a PHP array. Are you trying to output the results as JSON? That's a simple case of using `json_encode`...

Comment: I have tried, but to no avail. 
Will you help me code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

function getTree($path) {

    $dir    = scandir($path);

    $items = array();

    foreach($dir as $v) {

        // Ignore the current directory and it's parent
        if($v == '.' || $v == '..')
            continue;

        $item = array();

        // If FILE
        if(!is_dir($path.'/'.$v)) {

            $fileName = basename($v);
            $file = array();
            $file['name'] = $fileName;
            $file['size'] = '122';

            $item = $file;

        } else {
        // If FOLDER, then go inside and repeat the loop

            $folder = array();
            $folder['name'] = basename($v);
            $childs = getTree($path.'/'.$v);
            $folder['children'] = $childs;

            $item = $folder;

        }

        $items[] = $item;

    }

    return $items;
}


$path = 'data';
$tree['name'] = 'Main node';
$tree['children'] = getTree($path);

$json = json_encode($tree, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);


echo '<pre>';
echo $json;
echo '</pre>';

?>
```